# Typescript: How to make a generic version of compile-time set without runtime artifacts?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make Typescript warn me about incorrect usages of the API that we have (the errors I expect to see are marked):

```
interface Icon { src: string; }

interface IconSet {
  [iconName: string]: Icon;
}

type IconRegistry<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Icon;
};

function asIconRegistry<T extends IconSet>(iconSet: T): IconRegistry<T> {
  return iconSet as any;
}

type UiBuilder = <P, S extends IconRegistry<P>>(iconRegistry: S) => {
  withIcon<K extends keyof S>(iconName: K): null,
};

const listIcons = asIconRegistry({
  sort: { src: 'sort.svg' }, // Expected to be OK
  email: { source: 'email.svg' }, // Expected to ERR
});

const profileIcons = asIconRegistry({
  security: { src: 'security.svg' }, // Expected to be OK
  email: { src: 'email.svg' }, // Expected to be OK
});

function buildUi(builder: UiBuilder) {
  builder(profileIcons).withIcon('security'); // Expected to be OK
  builder(profileIcons).withIcon('bold'); // Expected to ERR
}
```

It works great, as can be seen [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Icon%20%7B%20src%3A%20string%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IconSet%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BiconName%3A%20string%5D%3A%20Icon%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20IconRegistry%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20Icon%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20asIconRegistry%3CT%20extends%20IconSet%3E(iconSet%3A%20T)%3A%20IconRegistry%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20iconSet%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20UiBuilder%20%3D%20%3CP%2C%20S%20extends%20IconRegistry%3CP%3E%3E(iconRegistry%3A%20S)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20withIcon%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20S%3E(iconName%3A%20K)%3A%20null%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20listIcons%20%3D%20asIconRegistry(%7B%0D%0A%20%20sort%3A%20%7B%20src%3A%20'sort.svg'%20%7D%2C%20%2F%2F%20Expected%20to%20be%20OK%0D%0A%20%20email%3A%20%7B%20source%3A%20'email.svg'%20%7D%2C%20%2F%2F%20Expected%20to%20ERR%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20profileIcons%20%3D%20asIconRegistry(%7B%0D%0A%20%20security%3A%20%7B%20src%3A%20'security.svg'%20%7D%2C%20%2F%2F%20Expected%20to%20be%20OK%0D%0A%20%20email%3A%20%7B%20src%3A%20'email.svg'%20%7D%2C%20%2F%2F%20Expected%20to%20be%20OK%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20buildUi(builder%3A%20UiBuilder)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20builder(profileIcons).withIcon('security')%3B%20%2F%2F%20Expected%20to%20be%20OK%0D%0A%20%20builder(profileIcons).withIcon('bold')%3B%20%2F%2F%20Expected%20to%20ERR%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Another%20way%20of%20doing%20this%20(but%20is%20too%20verbose)%0D%0Aconst%20listIcons2%3A%20IconRegistry%3C%7B%20sort%3A%20Icon%2C%20email%3A%20Icon%20%7D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20sort%3A%20%7B%20src%3A%20'sort.svg'%20%7D%2C%20%2F%2F%20Expected%20to%20be%20OK%0D%0A%20%20email%3A%20%7B%20source%3A%20'email.svg'%20%7D%2C%20%2F%2F%20Expected%20to%20ERR%0D%0A%7D%3B), except for one small detail - the `asIconRegistry` function is an actual runtime artifact, which is non-ideal.

#### What I've tried:

Typing the variables manually:

```
const listIcons2: IconRegistry<{ sort: Icon, email: Icon }> = {
  sort: { src: 'sort.svg' }, // Expected to be OK
  email: { source: 'email.svg' }, // Expected to ERR
};
```

This works, but is too verbose - the usefulness of generics is kinda lost. In addition to that this becomes harder to maintain as the list grows in size and complexity, and it is harder to persuade consumers of this API to type their things this way.

How can I achieve the same level of type safety without runtime artifacts and the above verbosity?

Comment: I am not sure why you need generics here. So, if you remove T, S and fix those to their respective type names, you can easily eliminate verbosity at the last step. Instead of `IconRegistry<{ ...}>`, `IconRegistry` should work..

Comment: @mcku if I remove type `T` from `IconRegistry`, then it will become the same as `IconSet`, wouldn't it? If so, the `buildUi` function wouldn't err out as expected. You can confirm that by posting [this gist](https://gist.github.com/DethAriel/701830b6e0a99843bd19bcfbb18197c1) to the TS playground

Comment: Oh, got it. Thanks for explaining that.

Comment: an identity function can not be inlined by typescript, i guess..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let's clean things up a bit.  Your generics are a bit wider than necessary; mostly you are using full object types when you only actually care about their key names.  Here's my changes:

```
// Icon is the same
interface Icon { src: string; }

// you just need key names here (K), not a full object type (T)
type IconRegistry<K extends string> = Record<K, Icon>

// you don't really need IconSet, but for convenience, here it is
type IconSet = IconRegistry<string>

// the old P and S didn't do anything except determine keys
// let's just use those keys (K) directly
type UiBuilder = <K extends string>(iconRegistry: IconRegistry<K>) => {
  withIcon(iconName: K): null,
};
```

---

So now you're ready to create and use some `IconSet`s.

I don't really understand why you think it's important to have zero runtime impact from your type checking (an identity function call is probably fairly low impact especially with [modern JavaScript engines](https://ariya.io/2013/04/automatic-inlining-in-javascript-engines)), but I like a challenge.  You want to verify that `listIcons` and `profileIcons` are valid `IconSet`s at compile time without anything being emitted into the JavaScript.

How about this:

```
type VerifyIconRegistry<T extends IconSet> = any
```

You need to pass a valid `IconSet` as the parameter to `VerifyIconRegistry<>`.  Let's see it in action with the invalid `listIcons`:

```
const listIcons = {
  sort: { src: 'sort.svg' },
  email: { source: 'email.svg' } 
};

declare var witness: 
  VerifyIconRegistry<typeof listIcons> // ERROR
  // Property 'src' is missing in type '{ source: string; }'
```

There's the error. `typeof listIcons` is not a valid `IconSet`.
 Note `declare var witness` doesn't emit any JavaScript.  It does add a variable named `witness` into ambient scope here at compile time... give it any name you don't need, and you can reuse it since `var`s can be redeclared.

Now for the valid `profileIcons`:

```
const profileIcons = {
  security: { src: 'security.svg' },
  email: { src: 'email.svg' }
};

declare var witness:
  VerifyIconRegistry<typeof profileIcons> // OKAY
```

That one worked (and we reused the `witness` name).

Finally, let's make sure we didn't break `buildUi()`:

```
function buildUi(builder: UiBuilder) {
  builder(profileIcons).withIcon('security'); // OKAY
  builder(profileIcons).withIcon('bold'); // ERROR
  // Argument of type '"bold"' is not assignable 
  // to parameter of type '"security" | "email"'.
}
```

Looks good.  Hope that helps; good luck!